# Cannot Make REST Request To Page With Broken HTTPS

Tags: rest, ssl, rest-assured

I'm using RestAssured in Java to try and make a get request to a webpage but I have not been successful because of SSL issues. A number of search have let me to trying to use 'useRelaxedHTTPSValidation()' but I've had no luck.

The exception I get is:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints
```

Here is the basics of what I'm trying to do:

```
    RestAssured.baseURI = "HTTPSWebsite";
    RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
    // RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation("TLS"); // Also tried this
    given()
        .log().all()
    .when()
        .get()
    .then()
        .log().all();
```

If I go to website in firefox I see:
SEC_ERROR_CERT_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM_DISABLED

In chrome I see:
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).

If I take out the 'useRelaxeHTTPSValidation()'
I get the error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't find out how to directly get that function to work but I found that adding the below two lines changed the security settings to allow all algorithms. From there everything worked.

```
    Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms","");
    Security.setProperty("jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms","");
```